# Error with building Apache Spark (java error)

Tags: java, git, apache-spark, sbt, bigdata

I downloaded Spark then Git then sbt and set the java but while I am building Spark and write this command in cmd (sbt clean assembly) it starts building then it gives me this error... So What is the problem here?

> [error] (streaming-flume-sink/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run p
>   rogram "C:\Program Files\Java\bin\javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cann
>   ot find the file specified
>   [error] (unsafe/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Pro
>   gram Files\Java\bin\javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the fi
>   le specified
>   [error] (network-common/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>    "C:\Program Files\Java\bin\javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot fin
>   d the file specified
>   [error] (launcher/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\P
>   rogram Files\Java\bin\javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
>   file specified
>   [error] Total time: 230 s, completed Aug 6, 2015 4:29:16 PM

Comment: It appears java is not installed correctly, make sure to download the Java JDK as well.

Comment: Thanks man! It was from the JDK.. Javac didn't work at that time